# Accessing Ubuntu guest (VirtualBox) node.js server from Windows host

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox, ubuntu-12.04, node.js

I'm attempting to set up a node.js server on my Ubuntu guest OS running on VirtualBox.

A simple "Hello World" HTTP server runs fine if I try accessing it from a browser on the Ubuntu image, but I'm struggling with opening the page on a browser in the host OS, which is Windows 7.

I'm using the "Bridged Adapter" setting in VirtualBox and am getting a 192... local IP address for the guest machine.

The server listens on port 8124, so I forwarded that port (TCP and UDP) in my router settings.

When I try opening [Ubuntu IP Address]:8124 in my browser, I get a 'could not connect' message. As I mentioned before, "localhost:8124" on an Ubuntu browser shows me the "Hello World" page I want.

Any help on this issue would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to open the Port  on your guest system too. I had a similar error in my system and also set the firewall rules after it was suddenly

Comment: I did a "ufw enable," then ufw allow 8124. Doesn't look like that did it either :/

Comment: Actually, it looks like I got it. I was specifying '127.0.0.1' as the address - I left it blank and it looks like it works.

Comment: How do I open a port on my guest system?

Answer (score 7):

It may be too late but I figured out a way to achieve it in very simple steps.

> - In Network settings of Guest OS, use `Bridged Adapter`.
> - Run Node.js server with IP **0.0.0.0** instead of **127.0.0.1** .

Above settings works and I can access the server from other machine in same networks as well.